# android extreme battery saver

Tags: android, battery

I'm after an *extreme* battery saver for android. My definition of extreme battery saving is basically:

- in flight mode when lock screen is active
- when not at lock screen, only the foreground app is active
- other background activity minimised

yes I understand this means I will not be able to receive calls or texts or any kind of notifications. I basically want the phone to sit there and do nothing other than what I tell it to do.

There are many battery saver apps and features, but I have seen nothing that comes close to this level of functionality, though it doesn't seem it should be difficult to do.